# Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, foreach

Tengo un problema con un foreach donde necesito traer varios item de un campo y estoy utilizando este codigo  en php 7.4

```php
<?php
$registros = "";

      $jsonIncluye = json_decode($value["actividades"], true);

      foreach ($jsonIncluye as $indice => $valor) {

        $registros .= "<div class='badge badge-secondary mx-1'><i class='".$valor["icono"]."'></i> ".$valor["item"]."</div>";
      }
?>
```

Comment: El error te indica que `$jsonIncluye` no es un iterable. ¿Podrias [edit] tu pregunta y agregar el resultado de `var_export($value["actividades"])`?

Comment: [{"item":"Resane de muro 2 m2","icono":"fas fa-tools"},{"item":"Pintura tipo2 4m2 1 mano","icono":"fas fa-tools"},{"item":"S/I tubo LED 18W 1m","icono":"fas fa-tools"}]'
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp108108\htdocs\clientes\vistas\modulos\missolicitudes.php on line 130
''
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp108108\htdocs\clientes\vistas\modulos\missolicitudes.php on line 130

Comment: ¿Cual es el resultado de hacer `var_export($jsonIncluye)`? Si es `null`, el problema debe ser que la cadena no este codificada en `utf8`

Comment: No tiene sentido que sea null, ya que `var_export($value["actividades"])` devuelve un valor correctamente

Comment: @anythingg, tiene sentido, ya que el resultado impreso es un `string` y el formato del mismo pareciera ser correcto.

Comment: Sería oportuno que el OP trate de ejecutar `print gettype(json_decode($value["actividades"], true));` Con esto sabremos si es problema del JSON si imprime "string"

Answer (score 0):

Si el JSON no está mal formado, puedes hacer lo siguiente

```php
<?php
$json = '[{"item":"Resane de muro 2 m2","icono":"fas fa-tools"},{"item":"Pintura tipo2 4m2 1 mano","icono":"fas fa-tools"},{"item":"S/I tubo LED 18W 1m","icono":"fas fa-tools"}]';
$result = json_decode($json, true);
$str = "";
foreach($result as $i => $val) {
    # var_export($i);
    # var_export($val);
    $str .= "<div class='badge badge-secondary mx-1'><i class='".$val["icono"]."'></i> ".$val["item"]."</div>";
}
print $str;
?>
```

[image: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()]

Si esto sigue sin dar éxito, el JSON que has recibido puede que esté malformado

Comment: efectivamente funciono con esta             <?php
$json = '[{"item":"Resane de muro 2 m2","icono":"fas fa-tools"},{"item":"Pintura tipo2 4m2 1 mano","icono":"fas fa-tools"},{"item":"S/I tubo LED 18W 1m","icono":"fas fa-tools"}]';
$result = json_decode($json, true);
$str = "";
foreach($result as $i => $val) {
    # var_export($i);
    # var_export($val);
    $str .= "<div class='badge badge-secondary mx-1'><i class='".$val["icono"]."'></i> ".$val["item"]."</div>";
}
print $str;
?>

Comment: Muchas gracias de verdad que si

Comment: Si te fue útil mi respuesta puedes marcarla como válida dando click al check que está abajo del contador de votos, muchas gracias.